# TraitsUI SetEditor how can I access the subset the user has selected?

Tags: python, traitsui

How can I extract the user's selection subset from TraitsUI SetEditor?

If the user selects `kiwi` out of the available options shown below, how can I access the list `['kiwi']`?

The screenshot comes from running the example code, https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/examples/demo/Standard_Editors/SetEditor_demo.py

[image: TraitsUI SetEditor]